# Typescript Pick<> type failing: Argument of type '"foo"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Pick<Bar, "foo">'

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have a use case which I think would be perfect for Typescript's [Pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) types.

Here's a trimmed down example:

```
interface CreditCard {
  name: string;
  year: number;
  expired: boolean;
}

function setValue(key: keyof CreditCard, value: Pick<CreditCard, typeof key>) {
  // do stuff...
}
```

However, when I try calling this function:

```
setValue("name", "rick");
```

Typescript (2.3.4) gives the following error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '"rick"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Pick<CreditCard, "name" | "year" | "expired">'.
```

Also, I do *not* have an instance of `CreditCard` available to pass in as an argument, so changing the function to take a `CreditCard` as a third parameter is not possible in my use case.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Pick<Obj, Props>` creates a type that looks like `Obj` with only the properties specified by `Props`, whereas your example is trying to use it to get the type of a single property, which should instead be done like this: `CreditCard[KeyType]`

Your setValue function should look like this:

```
function setValue<K extends keyof CreditCard>(key: K, value: CreditCard[K]) {
  // do stuff...
}
```

You set up a generic type K which is a string literal type for one or more of the keys of `CreditCard`.  Then you use that type to grab the type of a property off of `CreditCard`.  When the function is invoked, the type system will narrow `K` as far as it can and use that to figure out a specific type for the `value` argument.

Comment: For anyone interested, this is called a _indexed access type_, also called _lookup types_. Source: [Typescript 2.1 keyof and lookup Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html)